# TSocket: Could not connect to server (Connection timed out [110])

Tags: apache, hadoop, hbase, hive, thrift

Following this article

http://nousefor.net/55/2011/12/php/hbase-and-hive-thrift-php-client/

I downloaded the HBase and Thrift php client package and placed them in the var/www/thrift/ directory on my ubuntu machine and wrote this simple client code to open a connection and show the tables in the database. But the server keeps reverting back with the error message "Connection timed out[110]". Any ideas..?? Also the code executes fine when run on the server (Amazon EC2) with `$transport = new TSocket('localhost', 10001);`

```
<?php

require_once('thrift/src/Thrift.php' );
require_once('thrift/src/transport/TSocket.php' );
require_once('thrift/src/transport/TBufferedTransport.php' );
require_once('thrift/src/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.php' );
require_once ('thrift/ThriftHive.php');

//open connection
$transport = new TSocket('107.xx.xx.101', 10001);
$protocol = new TBinaryProtocol($transport);
$client = new ThriftHiveClient($protocol);

try{
    $transport->open();
}
catch(Exception $ex)
{
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}

//show tables
$client->execute('SHOW TABLES');
$tables = $client->fetchAll();
foreach ($tables as $name){
echo( " found: {$name}\n" );
}


?>
```

Comment: The error message means: (1) Thrift is not running (or) (2) The port is wrong. Were you able to find out the problem?

Comment: No I could not figure out the problem, but I could get the job done using JDBC. But I am still puzzled about the failure of this code.

Comment: I see, your server is on Amazon EC2. Make sure your Security Groups allows that port (10001?) to be accessible by the public.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you are not point to proper host as where you Hive master installed. Please check where your `Hive Metastore host` ip address.

It might be  helpful for you thanks.